# how to install ltcl3.2 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, tcl

```
package require Itcl 3.2
```

gives the error message:

```
can't find package Itcl 3.2
```

what is that mean?
I am using ubuntu 18.04 and what package is need to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/itcl3/), you do:

```
sudo apt install itcl3
```

At a standard command prompt.

Note that this also requires Tcl 8.5; 8.6 is not compatible (due to internal structure changes that itcl 3 pokes around inside of) and needs itcl 4 instead.

Comment: It might not give you 3.2, but it'll probably give you something compatible with it. Packages for Tcl extensions tend to be _very_ good about semantic versioning.

Comment: thank you, its work. another question: how to install tcldot?

Comment: Well, that would be another question, wouldn't it? You should check [`libgv-tcl`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/libgv-tcl)

Comment: @Mahdad Hi! Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the check mark if it solved your problem :D